# cannot update database table in ios

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I need to update my `sqlite` table. So I wrote a query like this

```
 NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET SONGNAME=\"%@\",SONGPATH=\"%@\" WHERE PLAYLISTNAME=\"%@\"",SongTitle,songPath,playlistName];

    const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        status=@"song Added";
    }
    else
    {
        status=@"Error occured";
    }
```

The problem is this always shows the status as Error Occured. What is the issue with my query. please show me

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
    -(NSString *)UpdateLocalPlaylist :(NSString *)playlistName :(NSString *)SongTitle :  

    (NSString *)songPath
     {
         NSLog(@"passed");
         NSString *status;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocalSongs.sqlite"]];

    NSLog(@"Database Path %@",dbPath);

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"open");

        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET SONGNAME=%@,SONGPATH=%@ WHERE PLAYLISTNAME=%@",SongTitle,songPath,playlistName];

        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            status=@"song Added";
        }

        else
        {
            status=@"Error occured";
        }

        return status;

    }

    else
        return @"Error Occured";

}
```

Comment: Post the entire code that you have used for update..

Comment: I posted the entire code

Comment: When you get an error, you should call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: FYI, you need to finalize your prepared statement and close your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way...

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET
 SONGNAME='%@',SONGPATH='%@' WHERE PLAYLISTNAME='%@'",SongTitle,songPath,playlistName];
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: But it gives an syntax error Missing terminating character "" near this UPDATE

Comment: @user2889249, Just check your TableName & Column Name must be same as Write here.

Comment: Your Table Name & column Name must be same as your Sqlite Database file.

Comment: yes but those are same,, all those are strings not char or something,, but still it gives the status as Error occured

Comment: Did you open the Database before fire the Query?

Comment: yes   sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        
        NSLog(@"open");

Comment: try to clean your Project, reset the simulator & run again.

Comment: Did you made sqlite3 object in your .h file?

Comment: Please give the answer of above question. Did you made the sqlite3 object in your .h file as database in code?

Comment: in .m I created like this static sqlite3 *database; all other DB functions are working Insert,select all are working,, only this update methosd is not working

Comment: please re-try single quote(`''`) in your query because your code is working for me with the `''` in my app.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? Because I am very eager to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

SQL use single quotation mark (') for string, not double ("). Double quote is only for object names (tables, columns ...).

Comment: Why you are repeating the answer again?

Comment: Because you have posted solution, not explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you try this:

```
update_stmt = nil;
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET SONGNAME=%@,SONGPATH=%@ WHERE PLAYLISTNAME=%@",SongTitle,songPath,playlistName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this also and let me known

Declare your query in this format (As you declared before)

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET SONGNAME=\"%@\",SONGPATH=\"%@\" WHERE PLAYLISTNAME=\"%@\"",SongTitle,songPath,playlistName];
```

and added a condition like this to check

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    status=@"song Added";
                }

                else
                {
                    status=@"Error occured";
                }
            }
```

Comment: And Check  all you parameters are right(ex: Table name , field name etcs..).

Comment: He is used "" or nothing instead of '' in query.

Comment: in sqlite manager I gave this UPDATE LOCALPLAYLISTSONGS SET SONGNAME="HOREN2",SONGPATH="/varrrrrrrr/mobile/Applications/35F237D4-B844-4B10-9D31-BD2B9774BDC7/Documents/LocalSongs.sqlite" WHERE PLAYLISTNAME="fhfhdg"  but it is updated. Then I copied same field names from this query. but it shows error occured

Comment: please check your attributes.